# Prevent Backspace into textbox when text sel reaching 3 letters length

Tags: javascript, textbox

In JavaScript , I want to include a fixed three letters in a HTML text box "TSY" ,then user only can add 4 numbers after them (Only numeric input) | TSY1234 |, when he/she presses "Backspace" ,numbers will be deleted till reaching "TSY" | TSY | then it won't be deleted,in other words .. I wanna make "TSY" is fixed behind users input ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`<input type="text" value="TSY" onkeyup="if ( this.value.slice( 0, 3 ) != 'TSY' ) this.value = 'TSY';">`

Comment: Worked fine as I wanted .. Thank you :)

Comment: @user3132629 - if this worked for you, then you should accept it as the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="TSY"
onkeyup="if ( this.value.slice( 0, 3 ) != 'TSY' ) this.value = 'TSY';">
```

as proposed by **Andrea** will work with **keyboard events** but will not with any modification made by mouse-events e.g. **`CUT`** and **`PASTE`**. Hence you need to forbid those using `oncut` and `onpaste` html events. So as a complete solution you need the following code-

```
<input type="text" value="TSY"
onkeyup="if ( this.value.slice( 0, 3 ) != 'TSY' ) this.value = 'TSY';"
oncut="return false;"
onpaste="return false;">
```